# Placing equation number on left with reqno option in amsart document class

Tags: equations, amsmath, numbering, amsart

Is there a way to force individual equations to place their equation numbers (or more specifically the result of a `\tag*{blah}`) on a specific side of the page regardless of the options to amsart.

I sometimes wish to use the equation enviornment to define 'requirements' in my papers which should look like:

R_e:  equation stuff

Where R_e is the equation tag.  R_e should be on the left even when reqno is passed to the documentclass.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to do this for the `equation` environment, define a command to be used in the equation environment:

```
\newcommand{\LeftEqNo}{\let\veqno\@@leqno}
```

For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LeftEqNo}{\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = 1,
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}\LeftEqNo
    x^2 + y^2 = 1.
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The `align` environment is implemented quite differently, and you will need the `environ` package used like

```
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{Lalign}{\tagsleft@true\begin{align}\BODY\end{align}}
\makeatother
```

Then use `\begin{Lalign} ... \end{Lalign}` for left-numbered `align` environments.

I'm afraid that various hacks of the same kind will be necessary for the other ams environments, but I can't list everything without knowing which ones you need :).

Comment: equation or possibly align is fine.  I plan to wrap this in a special environment for this construct and it will be one of those two.

Comment: When I try this (using pdflatex) I get an error: 
! Undefined control sequence.
\env@Lalign@process ->\tagsleft

Comment: @Sam Nead: I assume you might have a different version of the environ package. Can you post somewhere the result of `\listfiles`?

Comment: Using the command `\LeftEqNo` in `equation` as above, LaTeX reports the error "ERROR: You can't use `\spacefactor' in display math mode." and "\veqno ->\spacefactor 
                      \@m 
l.1567 \end{equation}". What is wrong?

Comment: @gofvonx I've updated with a full example.  I had forgotten to mention the need for `\makeatletter` and `\makeother` when one works with commands whose name contains `@`.