# leqno on even pages and reqno on odd pages

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like to have the equation number on odd pages to the right and on even pages to the left. I found this
[How to put equation numbers on the left or the right, depending on whether the page is odd or even](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122885/how-to-put-equation-numbers-on-the-left-or-the-right-depending-on-whether-the-p/122909#122909)
but it does not seem to work with the scrbook class.
Any ideas on how to modify this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\linespread{1.5}

\makeatletter
\def\mathlabel#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
\def\eqnWrite{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\EqnStat{\theequation}{\thepage}}%
  \@esphack}%
\def\EqnStat#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname eqn@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand\@reqnnum{\hb@xt@.01\p@{}%
                      \rlap{\normalfont\normalcolor%
                        \hskip -\displaywidth(\theequation)}}
\def\equation{\let\mathlabel\label$$\refstepcounter{equation}}
\def\endequation{\eqno\eqnWrite\@ifundefined{eqn@\theequation}{\hbox{\@eqnnum}}%%
     {\expandafter\ifodd\csname eqn@\theequation\endcsname\hbox{\@reqnnum}%
     \else\hbox{\@eqnnum}\fi}$$\@ignoretrue}
\def\@@eqncr{\let\reserved@a\relax%
    \ifcase\@eqcnt \def\reserved@a{& & &}\or \def\reserved@a{& &}%
     \or \def\reserved@a{&}\else%
       \let\reserved@a\@empty%
       \@latex@error{Too many columns in eqnarray environment}\@ehc\fi%
     \reserved@a \if@eqnsw\eqnWrite%
     \@ifundefined{eqn@\theequation}{\@eqnnum}%
     {\expandafter\ifodd\csname eqn@\theequation\endcsname\@reqnnum%
     \else\@eqnnum\fi}\stepcounter{equation}\fi%
     \global\@eqnswtrue\global\@eqcnt\z@\cr}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   y = ax + b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   a^n + b^n = c^n
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Replacing scrbook with report works fine.

Comment: How about helping us with the basics... can you set up a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` so we don't have do build everything from scratch? Can you do that? Using a package like [`blindtext`](//ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) or [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) to build text around some equations. Also whether one should consider multi-line `align`s that may span the page boundary.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the `scrbook` class but perhaps the following will help, based on the `changepage` package provision of odd/even page checking.

```
%\documentclass...
\usepackage{changepage} \strictpagecheck
\newcommand{\leftright}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
  % code for right eqno (which depends on your class and packages)
  \else
  % code for left eqno (which depends on your class and packages)
  \fi}
% ...
\begin{equation} \leftright
% ...
\end{equation}
% ...
```

If you don't want to keep adding `\leftright` after each `\begin{equation}` you can add it to the equation definition like:

```
\let\oldequation=\equation
\renewcommand*{\equation}{\oldequation \leftright}
```

and then just use `\begin{equation}` instead of `\begin{equation} \leftright`.

Comment: What code would you use for the if part? Not sure if I like the solution because it requires to change the whole (very large) document.

Comment: @diophantus7 I have extended my answer. It is up to you to decide on the code for the `\if...` as it will depend on the class you are using and also any maths-related packages you might be using. Perhaps you need to ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Thanks! While it looks promising and works most times, it does not work with a split environment inside a equation environment and also not with an align environment. Ideas on why this might not work?